# React Context : Wait context value to load Header

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Good morning, 
Here I try to use a context of authentication and user data that I receive from my connection api, I receive my data perfectly and the connection works, until everything goes well. But I'd like to move my context to my header to display it in the header.
But I have a problem, after login, I need to reload the page once before having the username on the header, I conclude that the header loads before the context updates the values . And I don't really understand how to wait for the context variables to be loaded before the header is displayed

Here my context :

```
import React from 'react';

export default React.createContext({
    isAuthenticated: false,
    setIsAuthenticated: (value) => {},
    userData: {}
})
```

Here my app.js :

```
const App  = () => {

    const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(
        AuthAPI.isAuthenticated()
    );

    const[userData, setUserData] = useState(
        authAPI.getUserData()
    )

    const HeaderWithRouter = withRouter(Header);

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated,userData}}>
            <HashRouter>
                <HeaderWithRouter />
                <div className="container">
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                        <Route exact path="/login" component={Login}/>
                        <Route exact path="/profil/:id" component={Profil}/>
                        <Route exact path="/register" component={Register}/>       
                    </Switch>
                </div>
                <Footer/>
            </HashRouter>
            <ToastContainer position={toast.POSITION.BOTTOM_RIGHT} />
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Here my header:

```
const Header = ({history}) => {

    const {isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated,userData} = useContext(AuthContext)
    const [isToggled, setToggled] = useState(false);

    const handleLogout = () => {
        authAPI.logout()
        setIsAuthenticated(false)
        toast.success('Vous êtes déconnecté !')
        history.push('/')
    }

    const toggleTrueFalse = () => setToggled(!isToggled);

    return( 
        <nav className="headerNav">
            <Link to="/"><img src={Logo} className="VSLogo"/></Link>
            <ul>
                <li className="navItem"><Link to="/teams">Teams</Link></li>
                <li className="navItem"><Link to="/tournaments">Tournaments</Link></li>
                <li className="navItem"><Link to="/esport">Esport</Link></li>
            </ul>
            {(!isAuthenticated && (
                <>
                    <Link to="/register" className="signUpBtn">Sign up</Link>
                    <Link to="/login" className="connexionBtn">Sign in</Link>
                </>
            )) || (
                <>
                    <span onClick={toggleTrueFalse}>{userData.pseudo}</span>
                    <div className={`userPopup ${isToggled ? "show" : ""}`} style={{}}>
                        <ul>
                            <li><span className="font-heavy red"><Link to={'/profil/' + userData.id}>{userData.pseudo}</Link></span></li>
                            <li>Paramètres</li>
                            <li onClick={handleLogout}>Deconnect</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>  
                </>
            )}
        </nav>
    )
}

export default Header;
```

Here a part of my login component to set IsAuthenticated :

```
const { setIsAuthenticated } = useContext(AuthContext);

    const [credentials, setCredentials] = useState({
      username: "",
      password: ""
    });

    const [error, setError] = useState("");

      //Gestion du submit
    const handleSubmit = async event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        try {
            await AuthAPI.authenticate(credentials);
            setError("");
            setIsAuthenticated(true);
            history.replace("/");
        } catch (error) {
            setError("Error");
        }
    };
```

Towards the end of the header, userData.pseudo is supposed to display the username, but if I don't reload, nothing.

Thank you !

Comment: Hi, How do you update the context?

Comment: The context is updated according to states in app.js (isAuthenticated, userData) 
and it's updated here `<AuthContext.Provider value={{isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated,userData}}>`

Comment: Yes but I don't see where you call setIsAuthenticated to update the context

Comment: Oh yes, he is in login page,I'll update my post

Comment: Ok but you are only updating the isAuthenticated and not the data object. The data object is only populated with the default value but never updated

Comment: Um, it's true...It's strange because isAuthenticated changes well after the login, if I log isAuthenticated it changes from true to false in the header, so it understands that the user is connected because the SignUp/SignIn buttons disappear, so no problem obviously...

Comment: The the isAuthenticated changed because you call setIsAuthenticated, but you are updating only isAuthenticated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a `useEffect` that will sync the user-data if `isAuthenticated` changes:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (isAuthenticated) {
        setUserData(AuthAPI.getUserData())
    }
}, [isAuthenticated])
```

Comment: I need more tests but I think it's working! 
I had already tried to use use useEffect but I think I forgot [isAuthenticated] at the end... 
I'll pass the subject to resolution after doing some tests, thanks!